# Removing sprites from group from another class generates error name not defined

Tags: python, pygame

In the game you move as simple blitted image with no walking animation or anything and try to collect keys on the way to open doors with and ultimately escape the prison you are held in.

I ran into a problem when trying to "hit" a guard which drops a key. When I try to remove the sprite from the group defined in another class it tells me the item is not defined.

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/-/Desktop/escapeprison/escape.py", line 329, in 
    current_level.npcs.remove(npc)
NameError: name 'npc' is not defined

---

```
class Level(object):


    wall_list = None
    npcs = None

    def __init__(self):

        self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.npcs = pygame.sprite.Group()



class Level1(Level):


    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        #(x_pos, y_pos, width, height)
        #[x, y, width, height, color]

        npc = Npc(480, 40)
        npc.move = 0
        self.npcs.add(npc)
        walls = [[0, 0, 5, 500, WALL],
                 [0, 550, 5, 50, WALL],
                 [0, 0, 800, 5, WALL],
                 [0, 595, 800, 5, WALL],
                 [795, 0, 5, 600, WALL],

                 [390, 0, 5, 70, WALL],
                 [390, 120, 5, 150, WALL],
                 [390, 320, 5, 150, WALL],
                 [390, 520, 5, 80, WALL],

                 [550, 300, 5, 300, WALL],
                 [550, 300, 150, 5, WALL],
                 [750, 300, 50, 5, WALL],
                 [600, 380, 1, 150, WALL],
                 #Sellien väliseinät
                 [0, 195, 390, 5, WALL],
                 [0, 395, 390, 5, WALL]
                ]




        for item in walls:
            wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4])
            self.wall_list.add(wall)
```

where the magic should happen is outside the class in my game loop where if i press space it checks if i'm close enough to the npc and should remove it from the list

```
if player.rect.x >= 440 and player.rect.x <= 520 and player.rect.y >= 20 and player.rect.y <= 80:
                npc_scene = 1
                current_level.npcs.remove(npc)
                npc = Npc(480, 45)
                current_level.npcs.add(npc)
```

"might also be needed"

```
levels = []
level = Level1()
levels.append(level)

level = Level2()
levels.append(level)

current_level_no = 0
current_level = levels[current_level_no]
```

Comment: Which sprite are you trying to remove? from what group? please make it clear what part of the code the raises exception and post the full traceback

Comment: im trying to remove the npc sprite, then recreate it few pixels below with another image(guard being knocked down, it has a scene switcher which i accidentally removed while removing my finnish comments which i tough would just confuse readers) the issue is its telling me theres no sprite named "npc"

Comment: can you edit your question and add the traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/-/Desktop/escapeprison/escape.py", line 329, in <module>
    current_level.npcs.remove(npc)
NameError: name 'npc' is not defined

Comment: You can't use names that don't exist in a reachable scope. Why do you think `npc` is in a reachable scope?

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that the variable name `npc` is not recognized by the interpreter in the code section where you tried to use it (`current_level.npcs.remove(npc)`).
In order to make it recognizable, you have to receive it as a parameter, or make it global.

Read about the variable scope in python [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

Comment: it works if i move:  npc = Npc(480, 40), npc.move = 0 and       self.npcs.add(npc) away from the class without adjusting the rest of the code at all, how would i have to adjust it in order to be able to use it from inside the class tho, as it makes creating more levels easier.

Comment: I added a link to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Add a collision check method to the Level class and pass in the player rect and then loop through the npc group and test them for proximity.  Change areas to have all the generic stuff, then each level is just the walls and the inherited npc code, something like this? :-

```
class Level(object):

    wall_list = None
    npcs = None

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):

        self.npcs = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.add_npc(x, y, width, height)

    def add_npc(x, y, width, height):
        npc = Npc(x, y) #and width and height if that's what they are for
        npc.move = 0
        self.npcs.add(npc)

    def collision_check(player_rect):
         for npcs in self.npcs:
             if npcs.rect.colliderect(player_rect)
                #remove and call self.add_npc with new co-ords
```